# Command quoting in bash function

Tags: linux, bash, function, alias

In trying to create a bash function which accepts arguments and passes them to another command I am encountering a problem in quoting the parameters correctly.

I am defining the following function:

```
function cluster () {
    dsh -acM -- \'"$@"\';
}
```

The usage of this command being to translate something like `cluster ls -l` to `dsh -acM -- 'ls -l'`.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
cluster () {
    dsh -acM -- "$*"
}
```

so that `dsh` gets a single string for the last argument.